# ListFragment android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

So first of all I know this is a pretty common exception but I tried my best looking for an answer before asking here.
here is the logcat (sorry for the bad formatting im pretty new to this site):

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.rome.codzombiesinfo, PID: 6315
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rome.codzombiesinfo/com.example.rome.codzombiesinfo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
     at com.example.rome.codzombiesinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
     at com.example.rome.codzombiesinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1046)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
     at com.example.rome.codzombiesinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is the fragment class:

```
public class ListviewFragment extends ListFragment {
    static ListView mainListview;
    public static Context context;
    static Article [] articlesToUse;
    static Bitmap [] thumbnailImages;
    static String [] titles;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the fragment layout file
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_fragment, container, false);
        mainListview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        context = getActivity();
        mainListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent articleIntent= new Intent(ListviewFragment.this.getActivity(), MainArticle.class);
                final String bodyOfArticle = articlesToUse[position].getBody();
                final String titleOfArticle = articlesToUse[position].getTitle();
                articleIntent.putExtra("bodyOfArticle", bodyOfArticle);
                articleIntent.putExtra("titleOfArticle", titleOfArticle);
                startActivity(articleIntent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public static void setListView(Article [] articles){
        if(articles == null)
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error_connection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            titles = new String[articles.length];
            thumbnailImages = new Bitmap[articles.length];
            articlesToUse = new Article[articles.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                titles[i] = articles[i].getTitle();
                thumbnailImages[i] = articles[i].getThumbnailImage();
                articlesToUse[i] = new Article(articles[i]);//
            }
            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, titles, thumbnailImages);
            mainListview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

I think that is where the problem is at but if you want to see my mainactivity.java or the main xml file tell me and I'll add it right when I wake up tomorrow. Thank you for helping! (or at least trying)

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Normally, with `ListFragment`, you do not override `onCreateView()`, as `ListFragment` handles that for you. If you *do* override `onCreateView()`, and you return some layout that you inflate, that layout *must* have a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"`. Yours does not.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping, and I decided to get rid of the code I had in onCreateView, move the code to onActivityCreated and only save the container and inflater so ill be able to get the view and operate on it (by using         View view= myInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_fragment, myContainer, false); but now I get this loading animation and nothing else (where the list view should be)

Comment: @RomEz: Make sure that you are populating the `ListView` with an adapter.

Comment: yes I do, but I think I'm doing it wrong. I'm getting the info from the internet and the list view should contain some of it but when the fragment is created and onActivityCreated is being called the arrays I use are still null. Do you think that what causes it? Do you have any solution to it - How to create the custom adapter after the info? Edit- now im getting a null exception probably because of this.

Comment: @RomEz: At this point, you should open up a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you can show your code that you are using to populate the `ListView`, along with full Java stack trace of the crash.